# Where is a good place to share my custom functions for Excel?

Tags: excel, function, lambda, share, forum

I've created a number of custom functions in Excel using LAMBDA and would like to post them online for other people to use if they would like. I'm wondering if anyone knows good websites for this.

I'd like to post functions that might help beginner/intermediate users of Excel who want the program to do things that seem relatively straightforward but actually require a lot of finicky work.

Below is an example. I reformulated the LEFT, MID, and RIGHT functions to return the nth word or words in a string, rather than character. Here is RIGHT.WORD:

**RIGHT.WORD(Text, [Num_Words])**

```
=LAMBDA(Text,[Words],LET(Wrd,IF(ISOMITTED(Words),1,Words),Txt,TRIM(Text),Total,WORDCOUNT(Txt," ")+1-Wrd,Chars,SUBSTITUTE(Txt," ","|",Total),Number,IFERROR(LEN(Txt)-FIND("|",Chars),LEN(Txt)),RIGHT(Txt,Number)))
```

**Description**

RIGHT.WORD returns the last word or words in a text string, based on the number of words you specify.

**Syntax**

**•Text** Required. The text string containing the words you want to extract.

**•Num_Words** Optional. Specifies the number of words you want RIGHT.WORD to extract.

o   Num_words must be greater than or equal to zero

o   If num_words is greater than the length of words, RIGHT.WORD returns all of text.

o   If num_words is omitted, it is assumed to be 1

**Examples**

| Formula | Description(Result) |
| --- | --- |
| =RIGHT.WORD("Fluid flows flourishing fluorescently" ) | Returns the rightmost word in the string (fluorescently) |
| =RIGHT.WORD("Fluid flows flourishing fluorescently" , 3 ) | Returns the 3 rightmost words from the string (flows flourishing fluorescently) |

Given the amount of forums for people providing questions about Excel, I expected there to be many places to also make posts about Excel that did not involve questions. I haven't found a good place for this, and not sure if it's because I'm (a) not utilising the websites properly that I already know about, (b) have missed some important website that would suit my goals, or (c) they are few and far between.

Comment: [GitHub](https://github.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [Gist](https://gist.github.com/) from GitHub, that is the easiest way and the [Advance Formula Environment](https://github.com/microsoft/advanced-formula-environment) (AFE) Excel Add-ins is integrated with Gist, in one direction only (maybe in the future in both directions), i.e. you can upload the functions you stored in Gist in AFE. You can define public or private files in Gist. Using AFE you can include explanatory comments like in any other script language and define your Excel function repository for you or to share via Gist. Here you can find some [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/writing-on-github/editing-and-sharing-content-with-gists/creating-gists). The following [link](https://gist.github.com/dlealv/ab46bc0f85c4741db1dad65eb5c65efe) is an Excel repository I am building for my own purpose. In case it helps.